# Changing existing colour map

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I would like to use the "jet" colour map but it is too dark red/blue at the end of the map (for maximum/minimum values). Idealy, I would like to have very similar map to jet that starts from light red and ends at light blue. I am not a python expert and I really struggle to do this.

I tried searching for another existing map that suits me, but I could not find any. Modifying existing map seems like a very nontrivial task and I could not find a way around it.

Comment: Maybe `rainbow`  or `turbo`?

Comment: Daniela, this is not a proper answer, but I want to suggest a 15' reading that could be immensely useful if you plan to heavily use colormaps in your work. [Choosing Colormaps in Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html).

Comment: The easiest option is to used existing colormaps, and / or set `alpha=` to lighten the color. `rainbow` is a lighter version of `jet`. [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1j1h.png)

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get a lighter "jet" colormap in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58288579/7758804) & [Creating a custom color map for heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74879016/13525512)

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/custom_cmap.html) describes how to create custom colormaps. From the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/fa21b426dafc5f1f5819f8e64f03abce65fba3d3/lib/matplotlib/_cm.py#L243) you can find that jet is defined as follows:

```
_jet_data = {'red':   ((0.00, 0, 0),
                       (0.35, 0, 0),
                       (0.66, 1, 1),
                       (0.89, 1, 1),
                       (1.00, 0.5, 0.5)),
             'green': ((0.000, 0, 0),
                       (0.125, 0, 0),
                       (0.375, 1, 1),
                       (0.640, 1, 1),
                       (0.910, 0, 0),
                       (1.000, 0, 0)),
             'blue':  ((0.00, 0.5, 0.5),
                       (0.11, 1, 1),
                       (0.34, 1, 1),
                       (0.65, 0, 0),
                       (1.00, 0, 0))}
```

In order to make the ends of the bar brighter, just add some red/green/blue at the extremities. Taking an example from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74879016/13525512):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

test_data = {"a":{"a":1 , "b":0.5, "c":-0.2, "d":-2.7} , "b":{"a":0.2 , "b":0, "c":-1.3, "d":-2}, "c":{"a":0 , "b":1, "c":-2.2, "d":-0.005}, "d":{"a":-3 , "b":0.9, "c":0.01, "d":-1.15}}
test_data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11,9))
cdict = {'red':   ((0.00, 0.25, 0.25),
                  (0.35, 0.25, 0.25),
                  (0.66, 1, 1),
                  (0.89, 1, 1),
                  (1.00, 0.9, 0.9)),
        'green': ((0.000, 0.25, 0.25),
                  (0.125, 0.25, 0.25),
                  (0.375, 1, 1),
                  (0.640, 1, 1),
                  (0.910, 0.25, 0.25),
                  (1.000, 0.25, 0.25)),
        'blue':  ((0.00, 0.9, 0.9),
                  (0.11, 1, 1),
                  (0.34, 1, 1),
                  (0.65, 0.25, 0.25),
                  (1.00, 0.25, 0.25))
}

custom_colormap = LinearSegmentedColormap('', cdict)
sns.heatmap(test_data_df, annot=True, cmap=custom_colormap)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]